# Disks won't stay unmounted

Tags: hard-drive, backup, automount

When not using my 2019 MBP, I keep it in a back room plugged into a bank of backup drives.

When I want to use it, I want to take it into the living room.  So, I go and dismount any drives that aren't doing a backup.  I could stop/skip a running backup, but normally, I let it finish and then dismount.  I don't unplug them, because only one is plugged in—it is a powered hub for the others.

Unfortunately, frequently when I come back, they're all mounted again.  I don't know whether this is triggered by auto-logout, by logging back in, or just some timer.  But it's irritating—I have to dismount again and wait for write buffers to be processed before I can unplug and move the laptop.

**Is there a way to make them *stay* unmounted?**

Comment: Not plugging it into the bank of drives, power for charging is separate.

Comment: It has nothing to do with charging.  When I unplug the drives from the left side, I also unplug the charger from the right side.  The charger is 100% irrelevant for mounting and I mounting drives.

Comment: Not plugging into the drives when not needed may help...

Comment: ?!? The point is not having to dismount the drives _twice_ when I want to unplug them.  When I am not using the laptop, the backup drives _are_ needed.